Eigenvectors of complexified linear map
Let $T\in L(\mathbb{R}^{2})$. Suppose $T$ has complex eigenvalues $\alpha \pm i\beta$ with $\beta\ne 0$. We know that if $V_{1}+iV_{2}$ is an eigenvector corresponding to the complex eigenvalue, then $V_{1}$ and $V_{2}$ are linearly independent. A usual proof proceeds by assuming they are not and achieves a contradiction. However, I want to know why we should expect this to be true. Is there a motivation?

If they were linearly dependent that would imply that $Tv_1 = (\alpha+i \beta) v_1$.

@copper.hat why? It is not immediate to me. I think this is analogous to how the proof by contradiction goes.

Suppose $v_2 = \gamma v_1$ (with $\gamma$ real) then $T(v_1+i v_2) = T((1+i\gamma) v_1) = (1+i\gamma)T( v_1) = \lambda (v_1+i v_2) = (1+i\gamma) v_1$. Since $(1+i\gamma) \neq 0$ we get $T v_1 = \lambda v_1$.
